Valid/Ready assertion not working as it should
This is an issue that has come up repeatedly over my career and I've never had much success understanding or fixing it, let's see if this is the day
Basically I have an issue in a unit-test that I have traced back to a valid/ready handshake, which does not obey the required rules.
The handshake is part of an AXI-MemoryMapped interface, in the waveform viewer I see the following:

As you can see, araddr changes (from 8 to 10) before it should. Data should remain stable while valid is high until ready is asserted and the handshake happens.
I immediately went searching for the peace of code driving those signals, which is a task in my TB:
task automatic read_rq(input logic [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] addr);
    s_arvalid <= 1'b1;
    s_araddr <= addr;
    @(posedge clk);

    while (!s_arready) @(posedge clk);

    s_arvalid <= 1'b0;
  endtask

As I mentioned this is not the first time I find this issue. In the past I have always solved it by just changing the code a little, even thought I don't really see the issue.
Basically we are putting the address on the bus and asserting valid, then we wait for one clock cycle, because even if ready is already high (which could happen) we will always hold the address one clock cycle. After that one cycle we check, if ready is not high we wait another and so on.
I assume there's some race condition here, but I don't fully understand what is causing it nor how to solve it.
If somebody understands what is going on here I would appreciate it :)
EDIT
Ok so pretty much after posting this I "kind of" solved the problem.
Turns out I had been doing some modifications and I had added some code to randomize a "ready" signal in my testbech.
I made a mistake and I had mixed blocking/non-blocking assignments like this:
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (rst)
        ready <= 1'b0;
      else
        // ready 30% of the time
        ready = ($urandom_range(0, 2) == 0);
    end

Notice how a blocking assigment is used to randomly assert ready.
Well, it turns out the arready signal from my capture above combinatorialy depended on this signal, so it was probably being asserted asynchronously and screwing everything up.
After replacing the = for a <= the handshake works.
Even though I have solved this particular instance I feel like I could still understand this better, so if someone can properly explain I would appreciate it

If you want to go deeper than what @toolic said in his answer, search 'verilog scheduling semantics'

The recommended coding style for modeling synchronous logic (such as flip flops) is to:

Use nonblocking assignments (<=)
Use @(posedge clk)

This applies to design code as well as testbench code.  This guarantees that you avoid Verilog simulation race conditions like you had in your code.
Note that task calls must also be aligned to @(posedge clk).
You are correct that using the blocking assignment caused the race condition.
